# PHP, nodeJS and sessions

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, session, keep-alive

I have an classical apache server delivering php files, and a nodeJS server (with socket.io, but whithout express/connect) used for real-time event management on that PHP website. I sometimes need to authenticate the clients connecting to the nodeJS server, but this authentication is lost when the user reloads the page, because it also reloads the socket.io client (I store the socket ID on the server, which gets lost at each refresh)
The question is: Is there a way to keep the connection alive in socket.io, or a way to link the apache PHP sessions and the nodeJS server? Or maybe a way to keep this authentication using cookies (knowing I must store sensitive data like user passwords and keys)?

Comment: Use memcached as your session storage handler in PHP, then use a [memcached module in nodejs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached) - now all you need is the session identifier.

Comment: That seems to be working, but how does PHP store sessions in memcached? is the key the session id and the value the JSON-encoded string of the $_SESSION variable or...?

Comment: You can maintain a separate array containing users who are logged in. Using socket ID is not a solution because on refresh, socket gets disconnected and connected. If user logs out, you trigger an event that removes the userdata from this array. But watch out for cases where user closes browser without logout. Your array might become too big containing redundant data

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`memcached` as your session storage handler in PHP](http://www.php.net//manual/en/memcached.sessions.php). Memcached is a simple key value store that can be accessed via TCP; there is a [memcached module available for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached).

PHP stores the session in memcached by using the session id as the key. The session data (value) stored in memcached is a serialized PHP object, *with a slight twist*. You can read more about this unusual serialization at [the SO question "Parse PHP Session in Javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226614/parse-php-session-in-javascript). Luckily though, there is already an NPM module out there: [`php-unserialize`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/php-unserialize).

---

Now for the How-To.

**Assumptions**

- memcached is accessible at 127.0.0.1:11211
- php.ini (or php.d/memcache.ini) is configured with: `session.save_handler='memcached'` and `session.save_path='tcp://127.0.0.1:11211'`
- you have installed the required NPM modules (2): `npm install memcached php-unserialize`
- you're ok with CLI

**Prepare**

First, just to get some test data to work with, save the following php script (`s.php`):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['some'] = 'thing';
echo session_id()."\n";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Execute it with `php s.php`, and it should put stuff in stdout:

```
74ibpvem1no6ssros60om3mlo5
Array
(
    [some] => thing
)
```

Ok, now we know the session id (`74ibpvem1no6ssros60om3mlo5`), and have confirmed that the session data was set. To confirm it is in memcached, you can run `memcached-tool 127.0.0.1:11211 dump` which provides a dump of known key:value pairs, for example I have two in my test bed:

```
Dumping memcache contents
  Number of buckets: 1
  Number of items  : 3
Dumping bucket 2 - 3 total items
add 74ibpvem1no6ssros60om3mlo5 0 1403169638 17
some|s:5:"thing";
add 01kims55ut0ukcko87ufh9dpv5 0 1403168854 17
some|s:5:"thing";
```

So far we have 1) created a session id in php, 2) stored session data from php in memcached, and 3) confirmed the data exists via CLI.

**Retrieval with Node.js**

This part is actually really easy. Most of the heavy-lifting has already been done by the NPM modules. I cooked up a little Node.js script that runs via CLI, but you get the picture:

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var PHPUnserialize = require('php-unserialize');

var mem = new Memcached('127.0.0.1:11211'); // connect to local memcached
var key = process.argv[2]; // get from CLI arg

console.log('fetching data with key:',key);
mem.get(key,function(err,data) { // fetch by key
        if ( err ) return console.error(err); // if there was an error
        if ( data === false ) return console.error('could not retrieve data'); // data is boolean false when the key does not exist
        console.log('raw data:',data); // show raw data
        var o = PHPUnserialize.unserializeSession(data); // decode session data
        console.log('parsed obj:',o); // show unserialized object
});
```

Assuming the above is saved as `m.js`, it can be run with `node m.js 74ibpvem1no6ssros60om3mlo5` which will output something like:

```
fetching data with key: 74ibpvem1no6ssros60om3mlo5
raw data: some|s:5:"thing";
parsed obj: { some: 'thing' }
```

**Warnings/Gotchas**

One of my PHP applications stores some binary data in the session values (i.e. encrypted), but the keys and the normal session object remain intact (as in the example above). In this case, **`memcached-tool <host:port> dump` printed a malformed serialized session string** to stdout; I thought this might be isolated to stdout, but I was wrong. **When using `PHPUnserialize.unserializeSession`, it also had trouble parsing the data** (delimited by `|`). I tried a few other session deserialization methods out on the net, but did not have any success. I would assume memcached is maintaining the correct data internally since it works with the native PHP session save handler, so, at the time of this writing, I'm not quite sure if it is the deserialization methods or if the memcached NPM module simply isn't retrieving/interpreting the data correctly. When sticking with non-binary data like ascii or utf-8, it should work as intended.

Comment: OK, so here's where I am: I got the PHP session ID via the PHPSESSID cookie (in socket.io authorization), after setting up memcached. But I can't save this php session ID (saving it in handshake.session_id doesn't work, I can't get it back in socket.on('connection') using socket.handshake.socket_id. Why?? Is there another way of saving this PHP session ID and get it back in socket.on('connection') callback? thx

Comment: @MagixKiller, Why do you want to save the session ID on the Node.js side? Every time a new socket.io connection is made, use the PHPSESSID to look up in memcached if the user is authenticated (e.g. `mem.get(PHPSESSID,function(e,v){authorized = v.isLoggedIn});`. Login/Logouts will be managed on the PHP side and trusted by Node.js. You can even go as far as storing privileged information in the session object, e.g. `$_SESSION['username']='MagixKiller'; $_SESSION['isLoggedIn']=true;`.

Comment: yeah, but how to get the PHP session ID then? we can't access cookies during socket during on('connection') events, can we? well, how to get PHPSESSID in mem.get(PHPSESSID, function() {});  ? or where is it defined?

Comment: @MagixKiller the client knows the session ID: get it via `var phpsid = readCookie('PHPSESSID');` see ["read a javascript cookie by name"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142337/read-a-javascript-cookie-by-name), then on the client side socket.io: `socket.emit('auth php',phpsid);`, finally on the server side socket.io `socket.on('auth php',function(phpsid){ /* now you have the session id */ });`. You're essentially authenticating _after_ the socket connection has started. _Disclaimer: I am going by socket.io docs/demos and have no direct experience with it._

Comment: The point is I also know it server-side, during authentication (using cookies). The only question is how to save it, to be able tu use it in socket.on('connection') event. Some people say it works as saving it in handshakeData but for me it doesn't seem to be working:
if I do req.php_sessid = cookies.PHPSESSID (in io.set('authorization'), I can't get it back by doing socket.handshake.php_sessid in io.on('connection'). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MagixKiller `io.on('connection',function(socket){console.log(socket.request.headers.cookie);})` per http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#request:request ...again, another untested guess. the connection event of io passes the socket to the callback, did you try [dissecting that argument to see what was available](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)? e.g. `io.on('connection',function(){console.log(util.inspect(arguments,{showHidden:true,depth:null}));});`

Comment: Yay, first solution works: I can get cookies in on('connection') using var PHPSESSID = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie).PHPSESSID; !!!
Thank's a lot for your help ;-)

Comment: I am getting error when any value contains pipe(|) like 'abc|xyz|'.                                            Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: @dipendra I would open a new question on SO. You don't provide enough detail (i.e. circumstance) to help with the problem, and the comments of this answer is not the place to have such a conversation.

Comment: I'm using PHP-FPM on CentOS and it is storing the keys slightly differently:
`memc.sess.key.49d64hkl1pb7q2emftke823k76`


So in the Node.js code my key becomes
`var key = "memc.sess.key." + process.argv[2]`

Comment: Isn't there some simpler mechanism than memcached?  If all you want to know is if the user is logged in properly, can't you just look for the session file directly on disk somewhere?

Comment: @Michael typically the Node.js and PHP processes run under different users, and the session files (assuming you're using the filesystem for session storage) are 0600, IIRC, meaning that the Node.js process wouldn't be able to read it. The place on disk is noted in PHP's `session.save_path` configuration. For more info on the session file contents see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4698432/1481489. Another assumption is that your architecture isn't distributed: using something like memcached/redis allows for multiple compute nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I think this link will be of some help to you
https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/php-nodejs-session-share-memcache/

Answer (score 2):

Though the thread is old I would like to recommend what I used for my project.
Instead of memcached you can also use Redis for session handling. 
I have used the [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) as php redis client.Instead of storing session to files you can save in Redis. Most of the heavy lifting will be done by apache. For every request apache will append the session values to the cookies.And it reads the session values from every request and validates it.

Setting required to save the php session to redis is also very simple.

session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://host1:6379?weight=1, tcp://host2:6379?weight=2&timeout=2.5, tcp://host3:6379?weight=2"

That's it.This will make php save the sessions to redis instead of the file. This will also move the session that are stored in files to redis.

Answer (score 1):

If your project stores session in database - some do - then you can consider using database as a transfer medium.

If analysis in your particular case shows promise, then node-mysql (or similar) can be used - see this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818312/mysql-with-node-js#)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [zamnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1481489/zamnuts) helped me make since of doing authentication and was the approach I was already taking. Thanks for that.

The reason I am posting is the for me some reason when using :

```
var PHPUnserialize = require('php-unserialize');
```

Kept giving me error

```
SyntaxError: String length mismatch
```

I am not sure why? I wrote a function that does the job for me and wanted to share in case it may help someone else.

```
function Unserialize(data){

  var result = {};

  if(data !== undefined){

    var preg = data.replace(/(^|s:[0-9]+:)|(^|i:)|(^|b:)|(")|(;$)/g,'').split(';'); 

    var a = [];
    preg.forEach(function(value){
      a.push(value.split('|'));
    });

    var b = [];
    a.forEach(function(value){
      if(Array.isArray(value)){
        Array.prototype.push.apply(b, value);
      }else{
        b.push(value);  
      }
    });

    var arr_A = [];
    var arr_B = [];
    b.forEach(function(value, k){
      if(k % 2 == 0){
        arr_A.push(value);
      }else{
        arr_B.push(value);
      }     
     });


     if (arr_A == null) return {};

     for (var i = 0, l = arr_A.length; i < l; i++) {
       if (arr_B) {
        result[arr_A[i]] = arr_B[i];
       } else {
        result[arr_A[i][0]] = arr_A[i][1];
       }
     }

  }

  return result;

}
```

I just call it like this:

```
var PHPUnserialize = Unserialize;

memcached.get(key, function(err, data){
   var memData = PHPUnserialize(data);
   console.log(memData.is_logged_in);
});
```

You should be able to modify the regex to suit your needs fairly easily.